# VSTS Work Item Reactivation Report

Tags: azure-devops

We would like to be able to see metrics on work items (primarily bugs) that have been reactivated after being marked as fixed.

My understanding is that TFS has this reporting capability but VSTS does not have it built in.

Is it possible to get this information via VSTS? Alternately, how would we go about getting this information via other options such as Excel or PowerBI?

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is was ever operator in the Query, that can retrieve the work items that changed to a state, for example: `Work Item Type = Bug`; `State Was Ever Resolved`; `State = Acitve`.

Regarding Reports, there is the [Work item revisions for reporting REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/reporting-work-item-revisions) or through [Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/powerbi/connect-vso-pbi-vs).

Update:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how I would use the Query part. Can I somehow create a raw query?

Comment: What do you mean raw query? Do you mean the query string? You can get the query string through [Query Rest API (wiql)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/queries#with-the-query-string-and-columns-and-sort-options):

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be comparing Activation Date and Creation Date, which should not be equal. [image]